# Manage Dependencies problem

Tags: views

[image]

1. I have created a view table
2. It has editable fields with dependencies

   If status = "rejected", the remarks textbox is visible

   If status = "waiting for approval", the remarks textbox is invisible

In the first row, the dependencies work fine.
But for the following rows, the dependencies are not working.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: How are you hiding / displaying remarks field based on status ? Using JS / CSS ?

Comment: I am using Conditional Fields module. Then manage dependencies.

The Dependent is the Remarks then the Dependee is the Status.